# Dates, Angularjs, WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime, asp.net-web-api

We've been having some real confusion about how to handle dates between Angularjs and WebAPI. We only care about the date,don't care about the time or timezone. The angular site posts a date object back to our api but the date object still has the timezone on it so, depending on where the user is, the date that gets saved is off by one day.

I'd rather not have to deal with these dates on a one by one basis so we put in an http interceptor for all puts and posts that is looping thru all form fields and stripping timezone off dates and just returning the date but this doesn't feel right.

Any suggestions on the best way to handle this?

**UPDATE:**

More details if it helps.  We are using kendo date pickers and setting the model values with k-ng-model.  This helps us get a valid Date object.  Today I removed the interceptor and added the following:

```
               kendo.ui.DatePicker.prototype.valueOld = kendo.ui.DatePicker.prototype.value;
           kendo.ui.DatePicker.prototype.value = function (e) {
               var val = this._value;
               if (val != null) {
                   this._value = moment(val).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
               }
               return this.valueOld(e);
           }
```

Now when a user changes a date the model value will be only the date and the time zone is ignored when sent back to the API.

In the API when dates are sent to the front end we have a formatter that strips off the timezone as well:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
            new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" });
```

I don't want our devs to handle dates on an individual basis.  We were originally doing this and there was no consistency in the code.

Comment: You should use UTC dates. Stripping the timezone without converting the date to UTC can cause even more bugs.

Comment: you are overthinking it. UTC everything and ignore times.

Answer (score 2):

Send and receive your dates as UTC. In Web API you can add this so that everything sent would be sent as UTC assuming the `DateTime` instance has property `Kind` set to `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // add this to whatever code you have now
        config.SetTimeZoneInfo(TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
    }
```

From `angularjs` send your Dates in the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format as UTC `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffZ`. Then you only have to worry about the time portion in any UI control that you use to display the date.

Comment: I think Jon's case is confuse because his api expect the given field to be a `Day` (which is a `Time Range`) not a `DateTime` which is a `Time Moment`. So should we use a `Moment` to represent a `Day` which sounds incorrect, or two `Moments` to represent the `Day` which is a `Time Range` or is there a better approach? Anyways, dates usually have confusing implementations whatever language I use, but it worth the discussion.